# Change color of pushpin based on latitude and longitude in Bing Map

Tags: bing-maps, pushpin

I am using Bing Map and there are several pushpins in the map. I have one table and on clicking on any row one javascript function executes and in that javascript function i am having latitude and longitude of pushpin based on selected row. Now i want to change the color of that pushpin whose latitude and longitude i have got from that row?
Thanks in advance.

```
function    func()
{
  var     latitude;
  var     longitude;
  //code to change color of pushpin already in map for these latitude and longitude
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to load the url of another pushpin image that is the color you want. But there are several other ways (that i know of):

**Xaml Method**

This will create a custom pushpin using Xaml:

```
<Canvas x:Name="POI" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="22" Height="22" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top">

  <Ellipse  Fill="#FFF7F4F2" Height="22" Width="22"/>

  <Ellipse  Fill="#FF4498FE" Height="17" Canvas.Left="2.533" Canvas.Top="2.541" Width="17"/>

  <TextBlock x:Name="POITextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFF7F4F2" Height="14" Canvas.Left="3" Canvas.Top="3" Width="16"/>

</Canvas>
```

**UserControl Method**

1. Add a UserControl and then use this code inside the UserControl tag:

> ```
> <Grid>
>     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>         <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
>         <ColumnDefinition/>
>     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>     <Canvas Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
>         <Image Source="ms-appx:///Images/pushpin.png" Canvas.Top="-45" Canvas.Left="-14" Height="50" Width="54" RenderTransformOrigin="0.593,1.74"/>
>     </Canvas>
> </Grid></li>
> ```
>
> **CSS Method**

An example might be entering 'mypinclass' within the pushpin options. Bing maps will add a css class called "mypinclass' to the pushpin container.

```
.mypinclass div{

color:red !important;

}
```

**Javascript Method:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function getMap() {
        // Initialize the map
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map($('#map').get(0), {
          credentials: "Your Bing Maps Key",
          center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.5, 2.75),
          zoom: 4,
          mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road
        });

            var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.5, 2.75), { text: '1', typeName: 'sampleCustom' });
            map.entities.push(pin);
      }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .sampleCustom div { color: Red !important; };
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="getMap();">
    <div id="map" style="position: relative; width: 800px; height: 600px;">
    </div>
    <div id="opacitySlider" style="position: relative; width: 400px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ILI thank u for ur reply but can we do it using javascript only and i dont want to create pushpin again, i just want to change its color.

Comment: added javascript example ^

Comment: sorry but it is changing the color of text in pushpin,not the pushpin

Comment: yes, and i'll leave that up to you since my examples should be more than enough for you to figure it out on your own.